# .findIndex is not a function for the array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I define en array in TypeScript:

```
caseLocations: Array<CaseLocation>()
```

caseLocations gets following data:

> {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}}

When I try to run

```
state.results.caseLocations.splice(
    state.results.caseLocations.findIndex((i) => i.objectid === action.objectId), 1
);
```

I get an error:

> caseLocations.findIndex is not a function

Why it is not working? I tried also `.map` function. The same error.

Comment: Simply because caseLocations is not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`caseLocations` is an object, but with number as keys.

You can know that because the brackets around the data you provided us `{}` means it's an object.

If it were an array it should have been like this: `[0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}]`. With those brackets: `[]`.

Comment: Is it wrong definition of array Array<CaseLocation>()? How then I have to define?

Comment: Well, either change your definition to Object<CaseLocation> or change the data received so it is an array.

Answer (score 1):

`caseLocations` is an object, not an array. To use array methods such as `splice` or `findIndex` you have to convert it to an array first using the `Object.values()` function:

```
state.results.caseLocations = Object.values(state.results.caseLocations);

state.results.caseLocations.splice(
    state.results.caseLocations.findIndex((i) => i.objectid === action.objectId), 1
);
```